# Table is not Showing in database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I created table in database and I can see the table when I log in by windows authentication .If I log in by server authentication I can not see the table. Thanks

Comment: only that table or all the tables?

Comment: The question is unclear. Write more about it.

Comment: all the tables..

Comment: I created a database and table by script using SQL Server Management Studio.  I can see the tables I created when I log in by windows authentication.If I log in by server authentication I can not see the table. Thanks

Comment: your sql server authenticated user doesn't have permissions to see the newly created table.  Remember tables have a four part name, owner is a component of that.

Comment: "your sql server authenticated user doesn't have permissions to see the newly created table" ... Can I give the permission?

Comment: @marc_s - he says "SQL Server Management Studio.", so microsoft.      Chuang - I have no clue if you can give permissions.   Table might also be put into a different schema.

Comment: @marc_s I am sorry . It's microsoft..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to refresh the object explorer "cache".

1. Click on the database name once in the object explorer.
2. Click the "reload" icon in the object explorer top bar. This will collapse your database properties.
3. Expand the database properties and tables. The table should now be there.